# Has any human ever had the choice to leave Earth permanently?

Tags: escape-velocity, humans, soi

> Far beneath the ship / The world is mourning
>   They don't realize / He's alive
>   No one understands
>   But Major Tom sees / "Now the light commands
>   This is my home / I'm coming home."
>
> Peter Schiling, *Major Tom*

I found myself waxing poetic after reading [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34266/what-exactly-turned-on-the-light-indicating-apollo-8-was-starting-to-fall-toward) about the indicator light to tell when Apollo 8 entered the moon's sphere of influence.

> When that light came on there was silence – it was a kind of dawning – we were witnessing the first time human beings were falling away from the Earth.

What goes up must come down.  It's a law.  This is simply how it works.  Or worked.  In the last century we developed enough technology to go up... and stay up.  Someone who enters the moon's sphere of influence can simply choose not to initiate any burn, and wait for their final destination on the moon, never to return to earth again.

But the moon is [destined to come home](https://www.space.com/3373-earth-moon-destined-disintegrate.html) as well:

> The Moon will be torn to pieces and every crater, mountain, valley, footprint and flag will be scattered to form a spectacular 23,000-mile-diameter (37,000-kilometer)  Saturn-like ring of debris above Earth's equator. The new rings will be short-lived. Theory dictates they'll eventually rain down onto Earth's surface.

So even those who have had the opportunity to spend the rest of their days on the moon (should they have chosen as such) were destined to return, though on a much longer timescale than one might otherwise think.

**Of the 533 humans who have been in orbit, have any of them been sent into space with enough propellant to *actually* escape Earth's grasp, should they have chosen to use the fuel in that manner?  Has any human ever had the *choice* to never return to Earth?** (or at least choice not to return with the blessings of ground control, in case there were any missions where the astronauts had the delta-V but not the authority required to use it)

Comment: Just a note: the Moon getting torn to pieces is not nearly as sure as it was believed not long ago. Moon is constantly accelerated by Earth's tidal forces into increasingly higher orbit, and opinions are on the fence whether it will a) enter mutual tidal lock with Earth, then gradually spin down and get torn to pieces, b) escape Earth's gravity, c) get swallowed by expanding Sun, along with Earth before either of two other options happen.

Comment: *Has any human ever been aboard a spaceship capable of leaving Earth's sphere of influence?* ('leaving Earth permanently' has been a choice of everyone who's ever set foot on the moon)

Comment: @Mazura No.  You didn't read the question.  The point is that the *moon* (and hence everything on it) is due to fall back to earth eventually. (Although SF questions that premise).

Comment: @MartinBonner True.  There's  more cut and dry phrasing of this to find humans who could have left the sphere of influence of earth *and* the moon.  I chose this phrasing for three reasons.  1) It's more poetic.  2) It's closer to what I'm actually interested in, and  3) in phrasing this way I also opened the door up for frame challenges like SF's comment above.

Comment: @SF - where are you getting this? We're loosing our moon at like 2.5 centimeters a year or something. How's that ever going to stop if it's outside the Roche radius?

Comment: The end of the linked article ends with, 'but maybe not, in at least two different ways'. And "is an unpublished byproduct of her research" - great. Show me the codez! To answer my own question: supposedly by drag from the expanded sun. (and, no, I didn't read it; I just read titles :)

Comment: @Mazura: The energy pumped into the Moon to raise its orbit comes from slowing down Earth spin. And once that matches Moon's orbital period, the "escape" will stop and the direction will reverse as other tidal forces dissipate the energy.

Comment: @SF. - Apparently you are correct (... probably). [Will The Moon Ever Stop Drifting Away From Earth?](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2018/06/13/will-the-moon-ever-stop-drifting-away-from-earth/#5a1458fe38d5) – Forbes/Quora

Comment: @Mazura: As I said, the three scenarios are close enough in their predicted time, and depend on variables too little known to authoritatively choose which one will happen. Moon's escaping will definitely keep slowing down as both Earth spins down and its gravitational influence weakens with the growing distance - but a large passing asteroid could then throw the Moon out of the (flimsy by then) gravitational grip of Earth. Sun's expansion timeline is very poorly estimated, so if the Moon isn't ripped out of Earth's orbit it will begin spiralling down. How long? Hard to tell.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

> Of the 533 humans who have been in orbit, have any of them been sent into space with enough propellant to actually escape Earth's grasp, should they have chosen to use the fuel in that manner? Has any human ever had the choice to never return to Earth?

Apart from the Apollo missions, no crewed spacecraft has had anything like enough propellant to leave Earth orbit.

Apollo is a very different story. After translunar injection, the Apollo CSM/LM stack could produce an additional 3600 m/s of delta-V by expending first the lunar module stages and then burning all the service module fuel. This is enough to reach Venus, Mars, the asteroid belt, or even Jupiter. However, the ship would only have crew life support for a couple of weeks at most -- not enough to reach any interesting destination alive.

Comment: I think you'd get more delta-V by first firing the CSM, then descent, then ascent module. (might get even more if one could use the descent module without the ascent module but I think that would be impossible. Also, firing all these in LEO would result in massive Oberth benefits. Still, obviously there was not nearly enough life support capacity to get anywhere far.

Comment: @SF The specific impulse of the LM and CSM engines is pretty similar; expending the LM descent stage first lets you drop dry mass sooner. (Unless you want to discard the service module, but then your consumables are down to hours instead of weeks.)

Comment: That sounds like a horror movie scenario where the crew starts cannibalizing themselves. Does the crew actually have access to lethal suicide injections?

Comment: @Mehdi that's a different, but also interesting, question. Let me know when you post it.

Comment: @Mehdi Hang on, they're in the notoriously unforgiving environment of space, sat on top of tonnes of explosives, supplied with breathable air by a sometimes-temperamental filter, kept at a survivable temperature by a sometimes-temperamental AC system - and you're looking to give them ***yet another*** way to die quickly?  What's wrong with any one of the myriad of things which they need to actively *stop* from killing them?

Comment: @Graham I think this has more to do with dying in peace with no pain, even if it is for few seconds.

Comment: @Mehdi Jim Lovell is on record as saying that if the crew wanted to commit suicide, they'd simply vent the cabin to space. They'd lose consciousness with little discomfort in seconds and die shortly thereafter. See [this QA](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22608/were-cosmonauts-equipped-with-poison-pills) for more on the topic.

Comment: @Mehdi: No. The astronauts said later the way to commit suicide was to open the cabin re-pressurization valve (it's supposed to be used while floating in the ocean).

Comment: It's worth noticing that the delta v to reach the moon is almost the same as the delta v required to escape earth, and to actually get in an orbit around the moon you'd need more than for escaping earth.

Comment: If you can reach the planets on a controlled trajectory there may be a chance to execute slinghot maneuvers and get very far (could one leave the sun's gravity well?). Although there'll presumably not be enough fuel left to perform more than one (and even that would be a moon shot, so to speak) because of the necessary course corrections.

Comment: I think a Jupiter slingshot would still leave you well short of solar escape. A second flyby would be impossible to arrange (no power, no comms) even if propellant was reserved for it.

Comment: @RussellBorogove *I think a Jupiter slingshot would still leave you well short of solar escape*  Perhaps not. As mentioned on other comments here, an additional 12.2 km/sec delta V is needed once the spacecraft escapes Earth.  The Wiki page on the [Oberth effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberth_effect#Parabolic_example) stated the Oberth effect can multiply the effective delta V by 4.58 in a Jupiter flyby.  Given the 3.6 km/sec delta V mentioned elsewhere, that might be enough.

Comment: (cont) I don't have much orbital mechanics experience at all, but I suspect getting an Apollo CSM/LEM spacecraft to Jupiter with enough fuel to pull of that would take quite a long time. It'd probably be ever-so-slightly more possible if only one astronaut were to perform the maneuver.  Let's call him Hal....

Comment: I just had to [ask](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34493/has-any-human-had-the-capability-of-leaving-the-solar-system).  :-)

Comment: You need ~3400m/s of that ~3600m/s just to reach Jupiter, so you've got ~200m/s for a powered flyby there. With a 4.58:1 lever that's another ~900m/s, which might get you into the vicinity of Saturn orbit, but no farther.

Comment: @SF. More delta-v but less life support.  I doubt you would get as far before you died.

Answer (score 32):

**[Soyuz 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_11#Death_of_crew)**

The crew did not return to Earth in their lifetimes. This interpretation is obviously not what you are talking about though. Instead what is of interest is human's remains that do not return to Earth ever. In this case there is also a definitive answer.

**[Clyde Tombaugh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clyde_Tombaugh#Death)**

> Tombaugh died on January 17, 1997, when he was in Las Cruces, New Mexico, at the age of 90. He was cremated. A small portion of his ashes was placed aboard the New Horizons spacecraft.

You may consider this cheating since it was only a small portion of his remains, but more than just a hypothetical, it actually happened, and not only did this portion of his remains escape the grasp of Earth, but also the grasp of the sun.

Comment: Neither of those are the kind of thing I'm looking at, but I applaud the clever reinterpretations, especially Clyde Tombaugh!  I had not even considered the case where the decision to leave the Earth's grasp was made on the ground, rather than mid-flight (and posthumously, no less!).  That's definitely in the spirit of what I was after, even if there's some definite technicalities involved!

Comment: @CortAmmon see also [Gene Roddenberry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_Roddenberry#Spaceflight)

Comment: For Soyuz 11, they died at 168 kilometres altitude, so they did not escape Earth's grasp and their bodies fell back to Earth.

Comment: @Cœur hence why I said they did not return to Earth "in their lifetimes." I mainly brought it up to highlight the point that the question really pertains to human remains and not living humans, before giving the answer as it pertains to human remains.

Comment: Dead people don't have choices, if you're going to start the pedantry.

Comment: To be even more pedantic, they did make the choice to go in their lifetimes. (Gene and Clyde, that is)

Answer (score 4):

No and yes.

Rockets are costly things and no human ever left Low Earth Orbit, except the Apollo astronauts. Others had not enough fuel to do that.

The Apollo astronauts had theoretically the option to contradict their mission requirements and choose death

- on the Moon
- on Moon orbit
- or somewhere between the Moon and Earth

by commiting a suicidal sabotage. They didn't do it on obvious reasons.

One of the worst known violation of their rules was as John Young astronaut [has taken a sandwitch](https://www.space.com/39341-john-young-smuggled-corned-beef-space.html) with him into the space.

The escape speed from the Earth from Lunar orbit is already very small, it is possible, that the few fuel of the Apollo - reserved for orbital correction - could have been enough to visit the interplanetary space - without any way to ever return.

Comment: "without any way to ever return" - you'd still be on an Earth-intersecting orbit. You could just sit and wait. Might get home, might smash into the Moon, might get swept by a lone asteroid. It will take a lone time and the probability is low, but you might still get back to Earth by accident eventually.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Yes, it would be intersecting and probably not very far from the orbit of the Earth, however a next hit of the Earth - after a year - would be still very improbable. The probable result would be a near-Earth travel after $\approx$ a year, and then a Tesla Roadster-like chaotical orbit. It is nearly sure, that the ship would not enough fuel to hit Earth, even if it would be still working (probably it wouldn't, the whole Apollo travel was planned for a week, not for a year).

Comment: @JohnDvorak When you exceed escape velocity, you're not in orbit. Barring other influences, escape velocity is, by definition, a one-way ticket that never returns. If the Apollo fuel was sufficient to reach that speed, it wouldn't be coming back. The one thing missing from this answer is, did they have enough fuel to do that?

Comment: "not in orbit" Around what?

Comment: @NuclearWang Apollo may have had enough fuel to leave Earth's orbit, but you need way more fuel to leave the solar system. I've checked.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Escape velocity from the Solar System is around 42km/s from the orbit of the Earth. The Earth is already moving with 29.8 km/s, so around 12.2km/s delta V would be enough to an escape from the Solar System. Now the problem is that typical satellites, probes have around some hundreds m/s delta V reserve after they've left the gravitational well of the Earth.

Comment: @TooTea Right, fixed.